# Laravel middleware documentación

Tags: laravel

Se trata del uso de middleware para autenticación.
Se que puede usarse en los routes pero también en los controladores

```
this->middleware('auth');
```

Pero veo que es posible seleccionar cuando se aplica con only o con expcept

```
this->middleware('auth')->except(['ruta','ruta']);
```

o

```
this->middleware('auth', ['except'=>['ruta','ruta']]);
```

Pero no encuentro ninguna documentación sobre el uso de except y only en middleware.
He buscado por todo el sitio de Laravel pero no veo nada relativo a eso. ¿Alguien sabe donde encontrar más información?

Comment: No sé si entiendo lo que estás preguntando, la documentación es esta https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#controller-middleware